# Get variable from outside function in a function

Tags: php, function, variables

I am trying to access an variable outside of a function.

Here is my test code:

```
function testPARENT() {

$var1 = 'TEST1';
$var2 = 'TEST2';

list_LOOP();
}

function list_LOOP() {

echo $var1

}
```

I know that I can do like this:

```
function ($var1, $var2) {}
```

But that is not what I want to do, because I have a lot variables, and the function should be used as a kind of include function.

Comment: You could use the keyword `global`, but passing them as arguments is the way to do here!

Comment: keyword global is not the best way, since It will go in a kind of loop, and the varibale change through down the loop

Answer (score 1):

There are many (php)-design patterns. 
For this you could use Singleton (actually this one is an anti-pattern).

Example of Singleton:

```
<?php
class Registry{
   private static $instance = null;

   private $storage = array();

   public static function getInstance(){
      if( self::$instance === null ){
         self::$instance = new self();
      }
      return self::$instance;
   }

   public function set( $name, $value ){
       $this->storage[$name] = $value;
   }

   public function get( $name ){
       if( isset( $this->storage[$name] )) {
           return $this->storage[ $name ];
       }
       return null;
   }
}

// usage example
$storage = Registry::getInstance();
$storage->set('test', 'testing!');

echo $storage->get('test');

function testing($storage) {
    $storage->set('test', 'TESTING123');
    return $storage->get('test');
}

echo testing($storage);
?>
```

I added a link below with some extra information.

http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function testPARENT() {
   global $var1;
   $var1 = 'TEST1';
   $var2 = 'TEST2';
   list_LOOP();
}

function list_LOOP() {    
  global $var1;    
   echo $var1;    
}
testPARENT();
```

To accomplish this you have to define your `$var1` variable as global